# load content from one php page in another

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have three PHP pages index.php, fetch_data.php and product_detail.php.

My index.php has three columns: filter options, products panel, detailed description.

When a user clicks on a product in the product panel, the detailed description should load product_detail.php.

When I have target="_blank" in fetch_data, this works and shows product detail, but I don't want it to show in a new window. Everything must be on the same page in index.php. I need it to work something like: onclick="loadQueryResults()". Problem I think is that I'm not sure the method will be accessible in product_detail.php if declared in index.php.

I tried javascript to load product_detail.php in a div in index.php but it does not reference the id of the row.

```
<!-- index.php =============================-->
<div class="col-md-6">
<br />
<div class="row filter_data"></div><!--Contains output of filtered data-->
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
<br />
<h4>Product Detail</h4>

<script type="text/javascript">
function loadQueryResults() 
{
$('#DisplayDiv').load("product_detail.php?id=<?PHP $row['id'] ?>");
return false;
}                    
</script>
<div id="DisplayDiv" >
<!-- This is where product_detail.php should be inserted -->
</div>
</div> 

//fetch_data.php=================================
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$total_row = $statement->rowCount();
$output = '';
if($total_row > 0)
{
foreach($result as $row)
{ 
$GLOBALS['id'] = $row['id'];

$output .= '
<div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-8 col-md-8">
<div style="border:1px solid #ccc; border-radius:5px; padding:10px; margin-bottom:10px; height:300px;">

<p align="center">

<strong><button type="button" onclick="loadQueryResults()" >'. $row['company'] .'</button>'. $row['company'] .'</strong></p>
ID : '. $row['id'].'<br />
Detail : <br />'. $row['detail'] .' <br /><br />
</p>
</div>
</div>
';
}
}

//product_detail.php=====================================

$connect = new mysqli($host, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
die('Connect Error('. mysqli_connect_errno().')'. mysqli_connect_error());
} else {

$id = $_GET['id'];
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$id);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `db` WHERE `id`='" . $id . "'";
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<br/><br/>";
echo "Company: <b>" .$row['company']. "</b>";
echo "Detail: <b>" .$row['detail']. "</b>";

}}
```

How can I get product_detail to display in DisplayDiv in the index.php page?

Comment: Nothing calls your `loadQueryResults()` function...

Comment: Read about AJAX it's basic way how to change content of the page without navigating to other page. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

Comment: @David I tried to call it as an onclick="loadQueryResults()" but did not work, and not sure how to call it from fetch_data.php..

Comment: @ian: Not in the code you're showing us you didn't.  Or if your use of past tense implies that you have *removed* that attempt then that still explains why it isn't working... That function won't execute if nothing calls it.

Comment: @David True. I have now edited it. Thanks.

Comment: @ian: For the elements with `onclick="loadQueryResults()"`, what specifically happens when you click them?  Is the function invoked?  Are there any error messages on the browser's development console?  Is the page being reloaded?  (After all, those are links and when you click a link the browser will go to that page.)

Comment: @David sorry for the back and forth, I resolved the errors, the original script did not have errors in the console and it still does not. Only the a href works and loads as stated without errors. So annoying! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

You got two ways.

1. Merge both files into one and make code according to your desier.
2. Use AJAX method to fetch data from the second php url and display it in desired file.